# Make equation look nicer

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have an equation which has a fraction to the power of another fraction. The fraction in the power is really small. I tried using `\cfrac` to change the size of that fraction but then the constant and exponential at the start of the equation became too small compared to the rest of the equation.

[image]

What is the best way to make this equation look good? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
\rho(T) = \rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\frac{1}{d+1}}\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A larger size for the exponent can be used, e.g. via `\tfrac`. Or the fraction expression can be written with a slash:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\rho(T) =
\rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{d+1}}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho(T) =
\rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{1/(d+1)}\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The use of `\tfrac` does the trick. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no single "best" way to make an equation look "good".

For the equation at hand, I'd like to suggest you use "inline" or "slash" fractional notation. That way, `T` will be rendered at "textstyle" size and symbols in the subscripts and the superscripts will be rendered at "scriptstyle" size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\[
\rho(T) = \rho_{0} \exp\Bigl[(T_{0}/T)^{1/(d+1)}\Bigr]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have your choice!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

 \begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \rho(T) & = \rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{d+1}}\right]\\
    \rho(T) & = \rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\frac{1}{d+1}}\right]\\
    \rho(T) & = \rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\nicefrac{1}{(d+1)}}\right]\\
    \rho(T) & = \rho_{0}\exp\left[\left(\frac{T_{0}}{T}\right)^{\nicefrac[\scriptstyle]{1}{(d+1)}}\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]